# Electromagnetic waves reflection?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

I have a couple questions regarding the EMW (in my case, 2.4–2.5 GHz) reflection:

1. Could dialectric materials reflect electromagnetic energy, and how does this impact the efficiency of such reflection?
2. How does the thickness of the material impact reflection?

Comment: Yes, dielectrics will reflect EM waves, but what is it you want to know about this? Like, what do you mean by "efficiency of such reflection"? People generally want transmission to be efficient, but yes, if you want the reflection to be efficient, that can be arranged, but then you need to tell us more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Feynman - [Reflection from Surfaces](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_33.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic has been studied by Dinh, et. Al for concrete: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950061821029779

[image: freq range permittivity for RF, from Dinh]

You can see that for the low GHz band, dipolar resonance (as Dinh claims, particularly from water) is dominant as the dipoles of the material will align to the impinging excitation field, leading to polarization. Since most materials have water, this is the strongest resonant molecule for most materials in this range.

For more practical effects and to answer your specific questions:

- Yes, dielectric (not dielectronic) materials can reflect electromagnetic (EM) waves, and the efficiency will depend on the impedance of the medium with respect to the reference medium through which it travels. Typically you consider air/material reflections and this is easily calculated from the reflection coefficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_coefficient
- The layer thickness importance relies on how far the impinging EM wave has to travel "within the material" to reach the back of the material, or any further interfaces, that will reflect the EM wave. If the material is infinitely thick, the impinging wave will be most likely absorbed by the material and only the first interface will be reflected.

Here is a more developed explanation of the reflection/transmission coefficient calculation: [http://phys.iit.edu/~segre/phys570/10F/lecture_12.pdf](http://phys.iit.edu/%7Esegre/phys570/10F/lecture_12.pdf)